# How to sum two cells into one and delete the formula after that?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this very niche problem. For instance Lets say the value in the cell A1 is 5 and A2 is 10, what I want to do is add A1 to A2 i.e A2 is now 15 and then when I delete the value in A1 the sum should remain in A2. I cannot use the paste special option to copy just the values because i want to retain the formula for later use i.e when I again input a value to A1 lets say 3 then the sum in A2 should be 18. Any help???
VBA code that triggers this sort of action will be helpful
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Use worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 1):

You just set the Value:

```
Range("A3").Value = Range("A1").Value + Range("A2").Value
```

Comment: Thank you! but this just adds up the sum into the other cell. My requirement was something else. No worries I have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the worksheet's code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab then View, Code).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1, A2")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        if application.count(Range("A1, A2")) = 2 then
            Range("A3") = application.sum(Range("A1, A2"))
        end if
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    If CBool(Val(Err.Number)) Then _
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not good at excel VBA and cant understand the "Applications" part. But anyways thanks for your input. I will surely try it.

Comment: I did it using this:                                        
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4).Value = "=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4).Value & "+" & Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 3).Value